# how to stop touchesEnded: withEvent: propogate from subView to ViewController?

Tags: ios, uitouch, hittest

I have a view being added as a subView of a viewController.
Both this subview and viewController all implement this method

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I found that when I tapped the subView, both these method will be called.
I want to call subview's `touchesEnded` only. How to achieve this nicely? (not to add a gesture in it)

In the `touchesEnded`, apple doc says this "If you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, if only as stub (empty) implementations."

what's the other method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close!

To prevent to pass touch event to superview, you should override all the methods for the touch events. Add all the touch event methods to your subview, then you should be OK.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

Comment: nice ,man ,it works!! and i found that i have to implement the touchesBegan only, it will works well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing the subview's `touchesDidEnd` why not do the whole work in the superview's `touchesDidEnd` something like this

```
if([touch anyObject].view == subview){
   return;
}
```

This way you will be able to know whether the touch was originally from the subview or the superview.

**Alternative** : You can implement both the methods in the superview and subview, but like the above code you can return the call in the superview, if the view it interacted with is the subview, and keep working in the touches code in the subview

If in case you want a different opinion plz let us know what you are trying so that we can give the answer accordingly

Comment: in fact , i want to seperate subview 'code from controller's code ,so there is no way to stop the delivery from subview to superview ?

Comment: In case of touches code I dont think it is possible, as touches on subview also fires the superview's code. All you can do is ignore the touches in superview's code like i mentioned but keep on processing the data in the touches n subview

Comment: brianLikeApple has given a interesting answer,we could have  a look at that,but still thanks alot -_-@souvickcse